# frontend+backend: koa-proxy error 404

Tags: angularjs, node.js, proxy, koa

I have a Node app as backend and I want to hook it up with an AngularJs frontend. They sit under the same repo, on different folders. My Node app is working fine, I can interact with it using Postman and the browser.

I went with the proxy approach, created a simple Node app to serve the backend using `koa` as follows:

```
module.exports = (function () {
  'use strict';

  var koa = require('koa');
  var serve = require('koa-static');
  var proxy = require('koa-proxy');
  var logger = require('koa-logger');
  var app = new koa();

  app.use(logger());

  app.use(proxy({
      host: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/',
      match: /^\/api\//
  }));

  app.use(serve('./app'));

  app.listen(8000);

})();
```

The idea is to have all requests issued against `/media` to be proxied to the backend. The AngularJS code looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.polls', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/polls', {
    templateUrl: 'polls/polls.html',
    controller: 'PollsCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
}])

.controller('PollsCtrl', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.polls = [];

  function getPolls() {
    $resource('/api/polls').query({}, {}).$promise.then(
      (polls) => {
        vm.polls = polls;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  getPolls();
}]);
```

But when I load the page, I get a 404 on the console:

```
angular.js:12701 GET http://localhost:8000/api/polls 404 (Not Found)
```

And my backend app didn't get any response. I tried changing the host on the proxy config to something dummy and got a different error, that confirms that the request gets proxied.

So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, indeed, a 404. I missed adding a logger to my backend application, thus I wasn't aware it was it that was yielding the 404.

It was only then that I noticed that the forwarded request still had the `/api` path, which was not being served by the backend. So, I only needed to redirect all `/api` calls to the proper ones and the issue was gone:

```
app.all(/^\/api/, function(req, res) { 
  res.redirect(req.originalUrl.replace('/api', ''));
});
```